# Организация и мониторинг большого проекта на FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, проект

Как лучше всего организовать большой проект на фасме чтобы не потеряться в логике? (16-18 тысяч строк кода)? Средствами макросов создать свой язык чтобы было нагляднее? Графически построить граф зависимостей? может быть еще что то?
(Си и др. языки не предлагать пожалуйста, таковы уж особенности проекта, что нужен именно фасм)

Comment: Ох. Не завидую я вам. А переубедить руководство насчёт C совсем-совсем не судьба?

Comment: Ничего лучше, чем все комментировать каждый блок кодом или псевдокодом (короче, играть в человека-компилятор), ну и разбивать все на кучу модулей-библиотек, в голову не приходит. Надеюсь, Вам за это хорошо платят.

Но я бы рекомендовал взять нормальный язык, а для желающих странного выхлоп декомпилировать и представить в виде исходника на ассемблере. Или поменять проект.

Comment: Мрак. Может, пора покинуть эту компанию веселых извращенцев? Что это за проект такой, что нужно все писать на ассемблере? Какая-то встроенная программа для микроконтроллера?

Comment: @mikillskegg, fasm, насколько я знаю, для x86/x86_64.

Comment: Я тут думаю… 20 KSLOC на ассемблере x86 это, по очень грубым прикидкам, 0.5—4 KSLOC на современных высокоуровневых языках. Если есть часть, которая неведомым образом требует жестчайшего реалтайма, где надо прямо вот считать такты процессора — ну, вот ее-то можно соорудить на ассемблере и подлинковать.

Сделать вечерами часть прототипа на любом языке, подразумевающим быструю разработку (выбирая язык под задачу), да, отпрофайлив, поставить перед фактом, что вот это было сделано за пару вечеров, а на ассемблере еще пахать и пахать.

Comment: @drdaeman Если подскажете на каком языке можно в run-time вносить изменения в синтаксис и изменяя старый, фактически создавая новый язык, без перекомпиляции всей программы целиком и при этом язык позволял бы генерировать высокопроизводительный код для real-time приложений.

Comment: @green: эээ... а вы уверены, что ассемблер позволяет вносить изменения в синтаксис языка (то есть ассемблера) во время выполнения написанной на этом ассемблере программы? в моё время ни TASM, ни MASM, ни nasm, ни gas такого не позволяли.

Comment: @green: «синтаксис языка» и «рантайм» это, для любых компилируемых языков (включая ассемблер), принципиально несовместимые вещи, если, конечно, не таскать сбоку компилятор. А если таскать компилятор (в тот же LLVM или JVM), то ассемблер будет, наверное, худшим из возможных не-эзотерических языков для его реализации.

Comment: Ну с обычными макроассемблерами было немало подобных поделок (напр. C-- образца 80х-90х годов). Разумеется, сейчас это уже археология.

@mikillskegg и не надо клеветать на микроконтроллеры. Там вроде основной язык -- C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проектирование сверху вниз.
2. Разбиение кода на модули и процедуры
3. По возможности избегать побочных эффектов (к примеру, свести к минимуму использование глобальных переменных).
4. Комментарии с описанием выполняемых в куске кода действий, в местах с неочевидной логикой - псевдокод
5. "Говорящие" имена функций и переменных
6. Макросы не панацея. Использовать их имеет смысл, только если есть какая-то часто повторяемая операция, либо если за счет них можно сильно сократить код (к примеру, макрос для массива строк), а в остальном замена привычных мнемоник на непривычные - не выход.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего дробить код на процедуры (подпрограммы), каждая из которых будет иметь малый размер (до 50 строк кода) и выполнять логически законченное действие. Эти куски комментировать и из них собирать блоки более высокого уровня. Именно таким образом было когда-то изобретено структурное программирование.

Comment: Э. Дейкстра в гробу не перевернётся от такой клеветы на структурное программирование? Хотя, как я понимаю, и при жизни-то ему про структурное программирование приходилось читать и слушать много чуши.